# Add some text after the 4 lines of the matching pattern using shell

Tags: linux, xml

I have a xml input file which contains below

INPUT FILE

```
<Formula>
<name>Total Invoices Released</name>
<comment></comment>
<sumType>Suspense</sumType>
<operands>
<operand>Total Hui Invoice Released</operand>
<operand>Total hdrt Invoices Released</operand>
<operand>Total hgfyu Invoices Released</operand>




<name>Total Deep Invoice Released</name>
<comment></comment>
<sumType>Suspense</sumType>
<operands>
<operand>-Total Deep Licensed Original </operand>
<operand>-Total Deep Licensed Original </operand>
<operand>-Total Deep Licensed Original </operand>
```

I want to search with "Total Invoices Released" and add some text after 4 lines of the matching pattern from  file.txt. Similiarly i want to search "Total Deep Invoice Released" and add some text after 4 lines of the matching pattern from file.txt. Th eoutput will be like below

I want an Output file like below

OUTPUT FILE

```
<Formula>
<name>Total Invoices Released</name>
<comment></comment>
<sumType>Suspense</sumType>
<operands>
<operand>-Total Licensed Original This is he</operand>
<operand>-Total Licensed Reversal This is he</operand>
<operand>-Total Licensed Original This is she</operand>
<operand>-Total Licensed Reversal This is she</operand>
<operand>Total Hui Invoice Released</operand>
<operand>Total hdrt Invoices Released</operand>
<operand>Total hgfyu Invoices Released</operand>




<name>Total Deep Invoice Released</name>
<comment></comment>
<sumType>Suspense</sumType>
<operands>
<operand>-Total Deep Licensed Original This is he</operand>
<operand>-Total Deep Licensed Reversal This is he</operand>
<operand>-Total Deep Licensed Original This is she</operand>
<operand>-Total Deep Licensed Reversal This is she</operand>
<operand>-Total Deep Licensed Original </operand>
<operand>-Total Deep Licensed Original </operand>
<operand>-Total Deep Licensed Original </operand>
```

I have coded but it is not giving me the expected output.

CODE

```
#!/bin/bash
IR=`grep -n "<name>Total Invoices Released</name>" BalanceForm.xml | cut -d: -f 1`
VIR=`grep -n "<name>Total Deep Invoice Released</name>" BalanceForm.xml | cut -d: -f 1`
TOTAL=`expr $IR + 4`
TOT=`expr $VIR + 4`
while IFS= read -r line; do
NAME="`echo "$line" | awk '{$1=""; print}'`"
sed -i "{
       ${TOTAL}i\<operand>-Total Licensed Original $NAME</operand>
       ${TOTAL}i\<operand>-Total Licensed Reversal $NAME</operand>
       ${TOT}i\<operand>-Total Deep Licensed Original $NAME</operand>
       ${TOT}i\<operand>-Total Deep Licensed Reversal $NAME</operand>
     }" BalanceForm.xml
done < file.txt
```

The input file is like below

INPUT FILE

```
C71 This is He
C72 This is She
```

Can someone tell me whats wrong with the code

Comment: You should tell us. What happens when you run your code?

Comment: is this for spamming/scamming?

Answer (score 0):

Just tried to tweak your existing code rather than trying new... Try this,

```
#!/bin/bash
count=0
IR=`grep -n "<name>Total Invoices Released</name>" BalanceForm.xml | cut -d: -f 1`
VIR=`grep -n "<name>Total Deep Invoice Released</name>" BalanceForm.xml | cut -d: -f 1`
while IFS= read -r line; do
NAME="`echo "$line" | awk '{$1=""; print}'`"
TOTAL=`expr $IR + 4 + $count`
TOT=`expr $VIR + 4 + $count + $count`
sed -i "{
       ${TOTAL}i\<operand>-Total Licensed Original $NAME</operand>
       ${TOTAL}i\<operand>-Total Licensed Reversal $NAME</operand>
       ${TOT}i\<operand>-Total Deep Licensed Original $NAME</operand>
       ${TOT}i\<operand>-Total Deep Licensed Reversal $NAME</operand>
     }" BalanceForm.xml
count=$(expr $count + 2)
done < file.txt
```

- keep the counter ticking and add to the line number, since the line number will increase in every append

Output:

```
<Formula>
<name>Total Invoices Released</name>
<comment></comment>
<sumType>Suspense</sumType>
<operands>
<operand>-Total Licensed Original  This is He</operand>
<operand>-Total Licensed Reversal  This is He</operand>
<operand>-Total Licensed Original  This is She</operand>
<operand>-Total Licensed Reversal  This is She</operand>
<operand>Total Hui Invoice Released</operand>
<operand>Total hdrt Invoices Released</operand>
<operand>Total hgfyu Invoices Released</operand>




<name>Total Deep Invoice Released</name>
<comment></comment>
<sumType>Suspense</sumType>
<operands>
<operand>-Total Deep Licensed Original  This is He</operand>
<operand>-Total Deep Licensed Reversal  This is He</operand>
<operand>-Total Deep Licensed Original  This is She</operand>
<operand>-Total Deep Licensed Reversal  This is She</operand>
<operand>-Total Deep Licensed Original </operand>
<operand>-Total Deep Licensed Original </operand>
<operand>-Total Deep Licensed Original </operand>
```